# UISearchBar tint color set to clear color

Tags: interface-builder, uisearchbar

I want to make custom appearance for `UISearchBar`in iOS 6 app, so I am trying to set tint color for it in Interface Builder as clear color. But when I am choose clear color in list it automatically changed to black! I am using `Xcode 4.6.3`
Is it an `Xcode` bug or this behavior is due to reasons?